# Beta site showing non-viewable, non-actionable flags in navigation bar

Tags: bug, flags, 10k-tools, beta-sites

On Project Management SE, I currently have ~8k reputation; that's enough for 10k tools on this beta site. For my account, the navigation bar at the top shows a count of one flag in the queue, but clicking on the link takes me to https://pm.stackexchange.com/tools/flagged, which:

1. Has no contents in the main section, so I can't do anything about the flags.
2. Shows [1 × not an answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/tools/flagged?flagtype=answernotananswer) in the column along the right-hand side. This link appears to do nothing when clicked.

This is a bug. Either I should see flags I can act upon, or the navigation bar shouldn't show me a flag count.

Comment: I've seen this too, and it's not a duplicate of the other question. (It's also not limited to beta sites.) See: [Flag counter in the 10k tools shows flags but I don't see them](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1510)